# How to nest a TabBarView's ListView in a CustomScrollView?

Tags: flutter, customscrollview

The thing I want to layout is like this
[image]
Because I want the ListView scroll with outside , So I want to make the ListView to the SliverListView .

But this will make the error:

> A RenderRepaintBoundary expected a child of type RenderBox but
> received a child of type RenderSliverList.

What's the best practice to do this kind of layout? do I have to change CustomScrollView to NestedScrollView?

Comment: try adding expanded over tabbarview and over list view if it is in column or row

Comment: @Pokaboom the listView will have some scroll problem , because I want to make the whole page scroll

Comment: I think @Bach's solution should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `SliverListView` is a `Sliver` widget, it can only be the direct child of `CustomScrollView`. Use it inside the `TabBarView` will cause the above error since `TabBarView` expect a `RenderBox` widget, not a `Sliver`.

In order to sync the scroll with the `CustomScrollView`, you can use this property:

```
ListView(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    // ... other lines
```